# Reduce WFS response size by reducing feature detail

Tags: geoserver, wfs

Using GeoServer 2.5.4 is there a way to request lower detail features? I currently have a 4.75MB response and each coordinate pair is extremely precise. Since the .shp providing the features may change occasionally I don't want to spend time optimising the file itself. I'd rather configure GeoServer or my WFS request to only return the coordinates to within 1m precision, or to only return those necessary according to some optimisation algorithm such as Douglas-Peucker. Is that possible?

Comment: Possible, but very expensive.  Better to generalize the source once and serve up different scale-specific sources.

Comment: It is possible to reduce the precision of coordinates from user interface Settings - Global - Number of decimals (GML and GeoJSON output). Setting obviously does not drop decimals from shapefiles.

Comment: @user30184: That sounds like a good setting, but in 2.5.4 it doesn't specify "GML and GeoJSON" next tot he box and when I tried it it had no effect on the JSON output

Comment: Sorry, I have only 2.10 installed.

Answer (score 2):

WFS does not have an option to generalize data, there is however a "vec:Simplify" WPS process that can do the job on the fly (at least in the currently supported versions, 2.9.x and above, I cannot remember what was around in 2.5.x).